# how to add default message to facebook statusbar(pinwall)?

Tags: iphone

hi  to all i am new to iphone,
 i need to post message on the wall of facebook by using this  url (http://www.facebook.com/connect/prompt_feed.php?message=hello) i can post message on wall but i want to post message dynamically means(access messages from database and  stored in array display all these messages on tableview when select message on tableview that  selected message display in wall of facebook)any one help to me how to post selected message on wall of facebook.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
http://www.facebook.com/connect/prompt_feed.php?message=[yourarray objectAtIndex:index]
```

Write the above code inside the below given method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok assuming you know how to post a specific message to FB wall, you can try the following:

1. Create a NSArray of all the strings you want to post to the FB wall
2. Populate the table view making the above array as datasource and implementing the [tableview delegate methods](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/Tasks/UsingTableDelegate.html)
3. You can get the index of the row selected in the delegate method didSelectRowAtIndexPath
4. Retrieve the item from the array and use it in your post string as follows

   @"http://www.facebook.com/connect/prompt_feed.php?message=%@",[myArray objectAtIndex:index]
5. Post the string to FB

Comment: thank you for your answer,i used same method like   (static NSString *kStreamURL = @"http://www.facebook.com/connect/prompt_feed.php?message=%@",twittermessage)but it gives error(twitter message means selected message on tableview,please give some idea thanks in advance.